# APIs dont work after restart wso2 api manager 4.0.0, Windows x64; works after redeploy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed to learn WSO2 API Manager, I have created some APIs. They work well until I restart the API Manager. It doesnot work when I restart API manager or the machine and it works when I redeploy the API. I am using Windows x64 and api manager version is 4.0.0

I restart the API Manager, The APIs dont work. I redeployed without any changes to a new revision and it works. same with every APIs I have created.

Comment: Is this the fresh pack you downloaded from the website? are there any errors printed in the log? What is the Windows version you are using?

Comment: @HeshanSudarshana It is downloaded from WSO2 website. WSO2 API-M v4.0.0 | © 2021 WSO2 Inc. I face the same in Windows 11 and windows server 2016.  Error from console: `[2024-02-15 09:20:29,419]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /test/1/*, HEALTH CHECK URL = /test/1/*`